# javascript: Defining "this" in the context of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When jQuery calls a function as an event handler for a raised event, jQuery is somehow able to define "this" in the context of a function that it calls. In the following example, jQuery define this as the dom element that was clicked on.

```
<input id="someButton" type="button" value="click me!"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $("#someButton").click(EventHandler);
     function EventHandler() 
     {
          alert($(this).attr("id")); //This raises an alert message "someButton"
     }
</script>
```

How does jQuery do this? I would like replicate this behaviour for my own custom framework.

Answer (score 3):

A `Function` has two methods that you can use: [call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2ak8h2y%28VS.94%29.aspx) and [apply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zc42wh1%28VS.94%29.aspx).  With both of these, pass the object you want to use for `this` as the first argument.  Using `call`, the additional arguments are passed one by one:

```
functionName.call(this, arg1, arg2);
```

Using `apply`, pass in an array of arguments:

```
functionName.apply(this, [arg1, arg1]);
```

Or, you can pass an actual arguments object:

```
function someFunction ()
{
    functionName.apply(this, this.arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `call` or `apply` JavaScript methods:

```
function myFunction() {
   // you want "this" to be your element
}

var element = SOMEDOMELEMENT;

myFunction.call(element, /* add other comma-separated arguments here, if any */);

myFunction.apply(element, /* add an array of arguments here, if any */);
```

When call and apply are used, it changes the context (`this`) inside your function to be whatever element you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what jQuery uses but there is a [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function:

```
var regularFunc = function() {
    console.log(this);
};

var boundFunc = regularFunc.bind(123);

regularFunc(); // logs whatever 'this' is at time it is called (e.g. 'window')
boundFunc();   // logs 123 at all times since that is specified to be 'this'
```

Answer (score 0):

its all in closure.

Javascript uses closure when defining variable like `this`.

so you can do things like:

```
var myFuncs = {

   func1: function(){
         this.func2 = function() { alert('hello');}
         return this;
   },
   func2: function(){alert('HI')}

}
```

so if you do:

```
myFuncs.func1().func2(); // alerts 'hello'
```

whereas:

```
myFuncs.func2(); // alerts 'HI'
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular old javascript/html also does it.

```
<button id='something' onclick='alert(this.id);'>Click me</button>
```